# How to model partition problem as Dynamic Programming problem?

Tags: c++11, dynamic-programming

I am unable to understand how this partition problem can be thought of as a dynamic programming problem.

I have the following doubts:

1) It is not an optimization problem (or I am unable to see) then why are we applying DP approach to it?

2) DP problems satisfy 2 properties:

1. Overlapping Subproblems
2. Optimal Substructure

   But I am unable to see the problem satisfying the above properties.

Partition problem is to determine whether a given set can be partitioned into two subsets such that the sum of elements in both subsets is same.

arr[] = {1, 5, 11, 5}

Output: true

The array can be partitioned as {1, 5, 5} and {11}

arr[] = {1, 5, 3}

Output: false

The array cannot be partitioned into equal sum sets.

Comment: Having verified that the sum of all elements is even (otherwise the answer is obviously false), think in terms of selecting a subset whose sum is half of that total.

Comment: Doesn't this question have at least one answer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_algorithm)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is NP-Complete but for smaller constraints it is solvable using dynamic programming.

The recurrence relation will be following:

**f(index,sum) =  f(index,sum + arr[index]) or f(index+1,sum - arr[index])**

and for the base case:

```
if(index >= arraySize) {
    if ( sum == 0 ) 
        return true;
    else
       return false;

}
```

The Time complexity and the memory complexity of this function will **O( arraySize * maximumSum)**. So if **arraySize * maximumSum** is small enough the problem is solvable using dynamic programming.